# $O(d,1)$ isomorphisms to $Sp(n;\mathbb{F})$ for some fields $\mathbb{F}$ and $n$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

The following orthogonal groups claimed to have the isomorphism ([see the Abstract of this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/prop.19820300202) or [here PDF](https://dokumen.tips/documents/superspinors-and-graded-lorentz-groups-in-three-four-and-five-dimensions.html)) to [Symplectic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_group):

$$O(2,1) \simeq Sp(2;\mathbb{R})?$$
$$O(3,1) \simeq Sp(2;\mathbb{C})?$$
$$O(4,1) \simeq Sp(2;\mathbb{H})?$$

See also [PDF](https://www.academia.edu/30368316/Superspinors_and_Graded_Lorentz_Groups_in_Three_Four_and_Five_Dimensions?email_work_card=title)

How to justify or falsify these isomorphisms?

> Do we have other isomorphisms?

$$O(d,1) \simeq Sp(n;\mathbb{F})?$$

for other $d$, $n$ and $\mathbb{F}$? or other than $Sp$?

Can we show these isomorphisms (by wise arguments, no need to be sophisticated proofs)?

(p.s. We also know that $Spin(3,1) \simeq SL(2;\mathbb{C})$.)

Many Thanks!

Comment: These should all be isomorphisms of Lie algebras; their $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ don't match. Note that for $F$ a field $\text{Sp}(2, F)$ is just another name for $SL_2(F)$ so you already know this second isomorphism, and the first one is similar.

Comment: You can find a discussion of these isomorphisms (including a fourth one for the octonions) here: https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2002-39-02/S0273-0979-01-00934-X/S0273-0979-01-00934-X.pdf

Comment: thanks +1 for refs!!

Comment: It looks to me: sl(2, R), sl(2, C), sl(2, H), sl(2, O) matches to so(2, 1), so(3, 1), so(5, 1), so(9, 1). The $sl(2, H) =  so(5, 1)$ is different from another resources PDF above I linked to -- do they got it wrong?

Comment: OP can you be clear about your definition of symplectic group for quaternions? (Also relevant is $Sp(1,1)$ is approximately $SO(4,1)$ in the sense of unitary group preserving the $1,1$ signature sesquilinear form)

Comment: I don't know what the author means by the symplectic group over the quaternions.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know either, I am only looking up this PDF: https://www.academia.edu/30368316/Superspinors_and_Graded_Lorentz_Groups_in_Three_Four_and_Five_Dimensions?email_work_card=title